# Extension of visa during UK visit for Indian Passport holder having US green card, residing in US

Tags: visas

i am US green card holder and I have a  6 month visa for UK issued in India for 6 months from 15th Oct,2018 to 14th April, 2019.   1. I visited UK from 15th Oct to 16th Nov, 2018. Now I am residing in US,  I need to visit UK again during April 1st to June 10th 2019. Can I apply for extension of my visa before April 15th in UK?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the question of whether you *can* extend your visa, the fee for doing so is an exorbitant [£993](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/extend-your-visa).  Even if you could, you wouldn't want to.

Instead, you should apply for a new visa before you leave the US.